# How to programmatically detect the login procedure (Face login, fingerprint, password, etc.)

Tags: c++, windows

I writing a program that logs user activity. Part of the logs is the login procedure of the user, for example by Face unlock or password.

Additionally, I need to log the failed attempts.

I can at least detect if user successfully logged in by Session change but as to how the user logged in, I can't tell.

Answer (score -1):

You can remember whether the login was done using Face Unlock or Password by introducing an extra variable to remember it.

```
enum class LoginType { FACE_UNLOCK, PASSWORD };
```

Now keep a variable of type LoginType with you and set it to the value from either the Face Unlock procedure or by using the password.

Comment: I’m understanding they want to know how *Windows* did the login, not their own application